# How to style a noneditable custom tag in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I've got a custom tag that I'm using within CKEditor which has been set to contenteditable=false. When I select the tag I want to be able to click bold, italic background color etc. to style it. Currently when I attempt to apply a style it attempts to apply the style/tag as a child to my custom tag and being that it is not editable the style is never applied.  Ideally I would like the style to be applied as a parent to my custom tag.

My custom tag is an inline one and looks like the following <ub:dynamic>My Text</ub:dynamic>

I was hoping that there would be a configuration that I could apply which would instruct the styles to be applied as a parent but I can not find anything.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to approach this problem?

I should note that I am using CKEditor version 3.6.5

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: CKEditor is 4.3.1 at the moment and it has changed a lot since 3.x. Update to the latest version first.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, at this point in time an upgrade is not really an option though.